# Eevee, lighting, Volumetric lighting crosses a mesh

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

I created two light spots with volumetric to get a beam of light with eevee in a real-scale scene. My light passes through my luster mesh despite having turned the shadow mode to none for the various shaders. If I activate the volumetric shadow I get a kind of sphere that hides my light in relation to the emission distance. If I mount the volumetric shadow samples, I end up completely losing my light beam. I have already tried to lower my light below the mesh but I always get the same result (for example in top view my light passes through my meshs to the rendering. How can I get this lighting visually, without my light passing through my mesh at rendering?[image]